# LateInitializationError: Field '_localPath@71099368' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview, flutter-downloader

I am trying to create a downloads_page to show download Item list from localStorage. I am using flutter_downloader with flutter_inappwebview widget.

I'm getting this error while downloading file from webview in the app.

Please help me fix this soon.

ERROR ON RUNNING APP:

```
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_localPath@71099368' has not been initialized.
#0      _localPath (package:myapp/pages/downloads_page.dart)
#1      requestDownload (package:myapp/pages/downloads_page.dart:578:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _WebViewTabState._buildWebView.<anonymous closure> (package:myapp/webview_tab.dart:359:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Can someone please tell how to initialize _localPath string here ?

CODE:

```
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:myapp/webview_tab.dart';
import '../models/download_list_model.dart';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';

final downloadsPageKey = GlobalKey<_DownloadsPageState>();
late bool _saveInPublicStorage;
late String _localPath;

class DownloadsPage extends StatefulWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  const DownloadsPage({super.key, required this.title, required this.platform});
  final TargetPlatform? platform;

  final String title;

  @override
  State<DownloadsPage> createState() => _DownloadsPageState();
}

// 1. a model class to store information about downloaded files:
class DownloadedFile {
  final String url;
  final String fileName;
  final String localPath;
  final int totalBytes;
  int receivedBytes;
  bool isPaused;
  bool isCancelled;

  DownloadedFile(this.url, this.fileName, this.localPath, this.totalBytes, this.receivedBytes,
      {this.isPaused = false, this.isCancelled = false});
}

// 2. stateful widget for the download page:
class _DownloadsPageState extends State<DownloadsPage> {
 
  late bool _showContent;
  late bool _permissionReady;

  final List<DownloadedFile> _downloadedFiles = [];

  final ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //DONE
    _bindBackgroundIsolate();

    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback, step: 1);

    _showContent = false;
    _permissionReady = false;
    _saveInPublicStorage = true;
    _localPath;
    _prepare();

    _loadDownloadedFiles();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() { //done
    _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Future<String?> getLocalPath() async {
  final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  return directory?.path;
}

Future<void> requestDownload(String url, [String? filename]) async { //DONE
  var hasStoragePermission = await Permission.storage.isGranted;
  if (!hasStoragePermission) {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    hasStoragePermission = status.isGranted;
  }
  if (hasStoragePermission) {
    final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
      url: url,
      headers: {},
      savedDir: _localPath,
      // fileName: fileName,
      showNotification: true,
      openFileFromNotification: true,
      saveInPublicStorage: _saveInPublicStorage,

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `_localPath` was not initialized in `initState` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your local path is where the downloaded files saved ,you need to initeate the path in your init state

in your case its something like this

```
_localpath = getLocalPath()
```

add this to your initstate

Answer (score 0):

Error could be caused by the fact that the `_localPath` String variable is declared with the `late` keyword, not sure why!

`late` in dart is used to declare variables without assigning any values. But some value has to be assigned to late variable right before its being used.

Which is nothing but a non-nullable variable that will be initialized later. Also, variable should be initialized which is not happening anywhere in the code, in return `LateInitializationError` caused.

If I want to fix it, I would be calling the `getLocalPath` function and assign its return value to `_localPath` in the `prepare` function.
Something like this:

```
Future<void> _prepare() async {
  // get local path
  _localPath = await getLocalPath() ?? '';

  // other initialization code
  // ...
}
```

Makes sense?

In this way, you should be able to avoid the `LateInitializationError`

Comment: ALso make sure that the `_prepare` function is being called before `_localPath` is used